# Wrong number of parameter prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, performance, prepared-statement, phalcon

I am using prepared statements to improve a query that I am doing, but it generates the error:

> Wrong number of parameters

The query is as follows:

```
$start = new DateTime('first monday of January 2016');
$end   = new DateTime('last day of December 2016');

$sql = "SELECT ".$generalLand."
                         product AS product,
                         Week AS label,
                         ROUND(SUM(harvest)/SUM(production),2) AS value
                  FROM (
                          (
                              SELECT ".$fieldLand."
                                     pr_products.product,
                                     CONCAT(YEAR(:dates),'-', LPAD(WEEK(:dates1),2,'0')) AS Week,
                                     SUM(IF(sw_sowing.type = 'SW', sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS PlantSowing,
                                     SUM(IF(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates2)),:dates3), sw_sowing.date)/7) >= pr_products.week_production AND sw_sowing.type = 'SW',sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS production,
                                     0 AS Harvest
                              FROM (
                                      SELECT max(sw_sowing.id) AS id
                                      FROM sw_sowing
                                      WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
                                      AND sw_sowing.date <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates4)),:dates5)
                                      GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
                                   ) AS sw
                              INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
                              INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product
                              INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON sw_sowing.id_variety = pr_varieties.id
                              ".$innerSowing."
                              WHERE pr_varieties.code != 1
                              AND sw_sowing.id_product = 1
                              AND sw_sowing.status = 100
                              AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = :id_tenant
                              ".$consultSowing."
                              GROUP BY pr_products.product
                              HAVING plantSowing > 0
                              ORDER BY pr_products.product
                          )
                          UNION ALL
                          (
                              SELECT  ".$fieldLand."
                                      pr_products.product,
                                      CONCAT(YEAR(:dates6),'-', LPAD(WEEK(:dates7),2,'0')) AS Week,
                                      0 AS plantSowing,
                                      0 AS Production,
                                      SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS Harvest
                              FROM pf_harvest
                              INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
                              INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = pf_harvest.id_variety
                              INNER JOIN pf_performance ON pf_performance.id = pf_harvest.id_performance
                              ".$innerHarvest."
                              WHERE pf_harvest.date BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(0-WEEKDAY(:dates8)),:dates9)
                              AND TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates10)),:dates11)
                              AND pr_varieties.code != 1
                              AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
                              AND pf_performance.status = 100
                              ".$consultHarvest."
                              AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = :id_tenant1
                              GROUP BY pr_products.product
                              ORDER BY pr_products.product
                              )
                          ) AS sc
                  GROUP BY product, label
                  ORDER BY label";

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $id_tenant = $this->getIdTenant();
        foreach($datePeriod AS $dates){

          $values = [
            ':dates'      => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates1'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates2'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates3'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates4'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates5'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates6'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates7'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates8'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates9'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates10'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates11'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':id_tenant'  => $id_tenant,
            ':id_tenant1' => $id_tenant

          ];

          $result = $this->db->executePrepared($statement , $values);

        }
```

I understand it's because of the number of binds I have in the query.

Each `:date` is the same date, but I put a different value because the variables can not be repeated.

I am also trying to improve my query, because I use a cycle that shows me the dates of each Monday of the year and those dates I put in the query.

For this reason I consulted in this way

If anyone can give me a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Regards!

Comment: Suggest Reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes I can give you a suggestion -- don't expect anyone to be able to help you with a question like this.

Comment: I am sorry I am going to update my question

Comment: You should check the value of $sql, perhaps it expects other parameters from the string concatenation.

Comment: I am going to review what is! @jlasierra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your foreach loop:

```
foreach($datePeriod AS $dates){

          $values = [
            ':dates'      => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates1'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates2'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates3'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates4'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates5'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates6'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates7'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates8'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates9'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates10'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates11'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':id_tenant'  => $id_tenant,
            ':id_tenant1' => $id_tenant

          ];

          $result = $this->db->executePrepared($statement , $values);

}
```

$dates is getting formatted 11 times. You realize this is the same date each time correct? Could this be the problem?

Maybe you meant something like this?

```
foreach ($datePeriod as $dates) {
  $dateHolder[] = $dates->format('Y-m-d')
}

$i = 0;

$values = [
  ':dates'      => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates1'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates2'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates3'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates4'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates5'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates6'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates7'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates8'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates9'     => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates10'    => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':dates11'    => $dateHolder[$i++],
  ':id_tenant'  => $id_tenant,
  ':id_tenant1' => $id_tenant
];

$result = $this->db->executePrepared($statement , $values);
```

Comment: I need the same date in every variable, for that reason I did that, but I am going to review!

Comment: If you need the same date in every variable, then just make a "date" variable and use one instead of 11 separate variables.

Comment: Yes, but I use phalcon and It only allows one variable in the query

Answer (score 0):

I know what is the problem:

When I use `executePrepared` I need to use three parameter, so in my case I need to use this:

```
$start = new DateTime('first monday of January 2016');
$end   = new DateTime('last day of December 2016');

$sql = "SELECT ".$generalLand."
                         product AS product,
                         Week AS label,
                         ROUND(SUM(harvest)/SUM(production),2) AS value
                  FROM (
                          (
                              SELECT ".$fieldLand."
                                     pr_products.product,
                                     CONCAT(YEAR(:dates),'-', LPAD(WEEK(:dates1),2,'0')) AS Week,
                                     SUM(IF(sw_sowing.type = 'SW', sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS PlantSowing,
                                     SUM(IF(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates2)),:dates3), sw_sowing.date)/7) >= pr_products.week_production AND sw_sowing.type = 'SW',sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS production,
                                     0 AS Harvest
                              FROM (
                                      SELECT max(sw_sowing.id) AS id
                                      FROM sw_sowing
                                      WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
                                      AND sw_sowing.date <= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates4)),:dates5)
                                      GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
                                   ) AS sw
                              INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
                              INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product
                              INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON sw_sowing.id_variety = pr_varieties.id
                              ".$innerSowing."
                              WHERE pr_varieties.code != 1
                              AND sw_sowing.id_product = 1
                              AND sw_sowing.status = 100
                              AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = :id_tenant
                              ".$consultSowing."
                              GROUP BY pr_products.product
                              HAVING plantSowing > 0
                              ORDER BY pr_products.product
                          )
                          UNION ALL
                          (
                              SELECT  ".$fieldLand."
                                      pr_products.product,
                                      CONCAT(YEAR(:dates6),'-', LPAD(WEEK(:dates7),2,'0')) AS Week,
                                      0 AS plantSowing,
                                      0 AS Production,
                                      SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS Harvest
                              FROM pf_harvest
                              INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
                              INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = pf_harvest.id_variety
                              INNER JOIN pf_performance ON pf_performance.id = pf_harvest.id_performance
                              ".$innerHarvest."
                              WHERE pf_harvest.date BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(0-WEEKDAY(:dates8)),:dates9)
                              AND TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates10)),:dates11)
                              AND pr_varieties.code != 1
                              AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
                              AND pf_performance.status = 100
                              ".$consultHarvest."
                              AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = :id_tenant1
                              GROUP BY pr_products.product
                              ORDER BY pr_products.product
                              )
                          ) AS sc
                  GROUP BY product, label
                  ORDER BY label";

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $id_tenant = $this->getIdTenant();
        foreach($datePeriod AS $dates){

          $values = [
            ':dates'      => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates1'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates2'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates3'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates4'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates5'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates6'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates7'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates8'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates9'     => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates10'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':dates11'    => $dates->format('Y-m-d'),
            ':id_tenant'  => $id_tenant,
            ':id_tenant1' => $id_tenant

          ];

          $types = [
            ':dates'      => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates1'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates2'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates3'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates4'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates5'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates6'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates7'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates8'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates9'     => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates10'    => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':dates11'    => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':id_tenant'  => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT,
            ':id_tenant1' => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT

          ];

          $result = $this->db->executePrepared($statement , $values, $types);

        }
```

I addes $types[], for that reason it did not working!

I hope that it can help another person!